# For stacked bar chart, how to render zero height bars as invisible?

Tags: pgfplots

I am creating a stacked bar chart using the nifty `pgfplots` package.  It turns out that many of my data values are zero -- only a few columns have nonzero entries in a given layer.  Using  the `ybar stacked` plot style, data values that are zero are rendered as a visible line (particularly noticeable for `thick` lines).

For example here is an MWE and its output:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar stacked, thick]
    \addplot+ coordinates {(1,3) (2,0) (3,0)};
    \addplot+ coordinates {(1,0) (2,5) (3,0)};
    \addplot+ coordinates {(1,0) (2,0) (3,3)};
    \addplot+ coordinates {(1,0) (2,0) (3,1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice the blue lines at the bottoms of columns 2 and 3:

[image]

Is there any way to have `pgfplots` render these zero values as invisible (i.e., not at all)?  For the example, this would mean that the blue lines at the bottoms of columns 2 and 3 would disappear.

Comment: One could install a `y filter` but that [doesn’t work properly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW9TT.png) with a stacked plot. Every other attempt to change keys or set low-level PGF values result in either no change at all or an empty picture.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That's a good idea; I had not known about `y filter`.  I tried `y filter/.code={\pgfmathfloatifflags{#1}{0}{\def\pgfmathresult{}}{}}` (is this the code you meant?) to see what goes wrong for the stacked plot.  Indeed, I get an error: "Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `1`. The unreadable part was near `1`.."  Is that what happens for you?

Comment: @HenryDeYoung You ran into a number parsing problem because #1 is an unnormalized number. If you say `\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{#1} \pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfmathresult}...` your approach should work

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Will have the same problem like my approach (I did it with an `\ifx` that compares to `0Y0.0e0`). @HenryDeYoung I would just set `every axis plot/.append style={draw=none}` or Tufte-like and get rid of the border in total. There’s no additional information in that border line IMO.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger As Qrrbrbirlbel said, yes, adding `\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{#1}` does indeed correct the error, but the plot does not appear correctly.  For example, instead of column 2 being a red bar from 0 to 5, as intended, column 2 now appears as a red bar from 3 to 5 (with nothing above or below).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That's a reasonable workaround, but I am still interested in a general solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose a general solution is simply unsupported by pgfplots.

It should probably become a feature request.

I hereby accept it as feature request and will add it to my todo list. For the time being, the workaround proposed by Qrrbrbirlbel (Tufte-like `every axis plot/.append style={draw=none}`) might be the best solution at hand.

**EDIT** The feature has been implemented in the meantime. The plot looks as follows with recent versions of `pgfplots` (and a suitable setting for the compatibility level like `compat=1.12`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar stacked, thick]
    \addplot+ coordinates {(1,3) (2,0) (3,0)};
    \addplot+ coordinates {(1,0) (2,5) (3,0)};
    \addplot+ coordinates {(1,0) (2,0) (3,3)};
    \addplot+ coordinates {(1,0) (2,0) (3,1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This may or may not be related to any such feature, but it would also be nice if the plotting could take into account `\pgflinewidth` so that the borders of the lower and upper neighbors butt up against each other, rather than one border overlapping the other.  To explain what I mean: In the example, it would be nice if the gray bar had a lower border, rather than that border being covered by the tan bar's upper border.

Comment: I see. I took a note on my todo list.

Comment: Any update? Did you implement this?

Comment: @user23127 Yes and yes, see my edit.